# REVERSE of a number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, reverse

used the following stored procedure to find reverse of a number , but it is showing error:use the right syntax to use near loop.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ggrepeat1()

begin

declare num1 int;

declare num2 int; 

declare rev int default 0;

set @num1:='&num1';

while num1>0

loop

set @num2:=num1 mod 10;

set @rev:=num2+(rev*10);

set @num1:=floor(num1/10);

end loop;

dbms_output.put_line('Reverse number is: '||rev);

end//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Seems like you're mixing MySQL syntax with Oracle. That's obviously not going to work. You can't use PL/SQL in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop in mysql should be used in this like.
This is the first problem

```
while n>0 do
    content..
end while
```

The second problem is

```
dbms_output.put_line('Reverse number is: '||rev);
```

In mysql you cannot use the above code.
Instead you can use this

```
Select 'The reverse of number is 'rev;
```

So your code would be

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ggrepeat1()

begin

declare num1 int;

declare num2 int; 

declare rev int default 0;

set @num1:='&num1';

while num1>0 do

set @num2:=num1 mod 10;

set @rev:=num2+(rev*10);

set @num1:=floor(num1/10);

end while;

Select 'Reverse number is: 'rev;

end//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: how to accept input from user, the command set @num1:='&num1' is not working

Comment: '&' works in oracle not in mysql.I think you have to pass it as parameter

Comment: Select 'Reverse number is: 'rev; not printing the reverse of number

Comment: It will print it as a table.

Comment: It will print it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can't use [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) syntax in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Regardless, I think you're over-complicating things. A simpler approach would be to cast your number to a string, reverse it using built-in functions and cast it back to a number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION reverse_int(num INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CAST(REVERSE(CAST(num AS CHAT)) AS INT);
```