# Reversing a number in sql using a procedure or function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to reverse a number in Sql. I have both PHPmyadmin and Sql management studio, but the following code is not executing. The original code was available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853539/reverse-of-a-number-in-mysql) . Thanks

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ggrepeat1()

begin

declare num1 int;

declare num2 int; 

declare rev int default 0;

set @num1:='&num1';

while num1>0 do

set @num2:=num1 mod 10;

set @rev:=num2+(rev*10);

set @num1:=floor(num1/10);

end while;

Select 'Reverse number is: 'rev;

end//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "reverse a number"?  The code you have shown is MySQL, so I changed the tag.

Comment: Like 123 should be changed to 321.

Comment: That's not valid T-SQL, and '&num1' is a piece of text

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the string representation in base 10 to be reversed -- so 123 becomes 321 -- then just use `reverse()`:

```
select reverse(x)
```

If you want this as a *number* rather than a string, then convert back to a number:

```
seledt reverse(x) + 0
```

Comment: How can I use this approach inside a function?